# What is this format of programming? Is there any way to deobfuscate / decode it?

Tags: decode, metamask, deobfuscation

```
function _0x16295c(_0x575472,_0x2dd521,_0x124a23,_0x81243a,_0x14bda1){return _0x2f8a(_0x14bda1-0x50,_0x124a23);}(function(_0x59ff99,_0x3258d1){var _0x2d0fea=_0x59ff99();function _0x1a41a7(_0x57ebe0,_0x466b04,_0x3d9cbe,_0x239147,_0x3eb87f){return _0x2f8a(_0x3d9cbe-0x1c4,_0x3eb87f);}function _0x3dd382(_0x20afa5,_0x29092f,_0xdd4ef6,_0x4d8efe,_0x3fdee4){return _0x2f8a(_0x29092f- -0x3c,_0x20afa5);}function _0x34e368(_0x471605,_0x176faa,_0x5e85f0,_0x5cbd21,_0x15e925){return _0x2f8a(_0x15e925- -0x36e,_0x471605);}function _0x7112bc(_0x52d676,_0x573e2f,_0x18222a,_0x3c5c49,_0x175393){return _0x2f8a(_0x18222a- -0x12,_0x3c5c49);}function _0x5b4232(_0x142c20,_0x332a8a,_0x46a7b3,_0x3c0040,_0x4a2c4d){return _0x2f8a(_0x4a2c4d-0x303,_0x332a8a);}while(!![]){try{var _0x84f6a9=-parseInt(_0x34e368(0x10c7,0x95e,0xc3b,0x79c,0x926))/(-0x1757+-0x2bf*-0x8+0x10*0x16)*(parseInt(_0x5b4232(0x10cc,0x18ba,0x1772,0x1461,0x1050))/(0x6*-0x3ea+-0x34d+0x13*0x169))+parseInt(_0x5b4232(0xe04,0x1406,0xd20,0xe3a,0x160b))/(-0x1f38+0x159b+-0x268*-0x4)+parseInt(_0x3dd382(0x265,0x17d,-0x408,-0x4d7,0x2f4))/(-0x4ee*-0x3+0x98*-0x38+0x127a)*(-parseInt(_0x5b4232(0x1934,0x192b,0x1936,0x1c96,0x1366))/(-0x14fa+-0x208c+0x358b))+-parseInt(_0x5b4232(0x1142,0x11c0,0x1118,0x18d2,0xff4))/(0x23bd+-0x1*-0xb7+0x246e*-0x1)+parseInt(_0x5b4232(0x1bbe,0x159a,0x211f,0x1c12,0x17ba))/(-0x3*0xb35+0x2*-0x6d1+0x2f48)*(-parseInt(_0x34e368(0xfdf,0x91c,0xf65,-0x19,0xa05))/(0x2005+0x204*0x13+0x4649*-0x1))+-parseInt(_0x5b4232(-0x482,0xc3,0x84e,0xe72,0x585))/(0x1*0x1d95+-0x1*-0xfcc+-0x2d58)*(-parseInt(_0x3dd382(0x16a,0x782,-0x91,0xc5d,0x1032))/(-0x204a+0xbab*0x1+-0x1*-0x14a9))+parseInt(_0x5b4232(0x2098,0x1804,0x1b97,0x1e6a,0x17dc))/(0x1*-0x2063+-0x945+0x29b3)*(parseInt(_0x3dd382(0x808,0xcc6,0x59d,0x51d,0x88c))/(0x475*-0x8+0x51c+0x1e98));if(_0x84f6a9===_0x3258d1)break;else _0x2d0fea['push'](_0x2d0fea['shift']());}catch(_0x19a3e0){_0x2d0fea['push'](_0x2d0fea['shift']());}}}(_0x5332,0x2f*-0x26f+0x116990+-0x9*0xb0b6));const max=document[_0x4d7e8b(-0x338,0xbe0,0xbff,0x379,0x35f)+_0x5dfd40(0xb40,0x1080,0xf51,0x12f4,0x94e)+_0x4d7e8b(0x77d,0x61c,-0x184,0x2d4,0x352)](_0x4d7e8b(0x341,0x5c3,0xead,-0x51,0x6e6)),input=document[_0x16295c(0x5ee,0xac1,0x401,-0x3e6,0x439)+_0x16295c(0x134b,0x9be,0xbe7,0x1655,0xef1)+_0x5dfd40(0x7b,0x7c0,0x56a,0x9ab,-0x5b1)](_0x4fee8b(0xfdf,0x82c,0x78c,0x18ef,0xa25)+'t'),price=document[_0x26b463(-0x804,0x355,0x4e3,-0x2d1,0x51)+_0x4d7e8b(0x105e,0xaf9,0xd96,0xa4a,0xe17)+_0x16295c(0x38,-0x24b,-0x10e,0xc73,0x42c)](_0x26b463(0x1893,0x194b,0x886,0xfaf,0xfe7));function updatePrice(){var _0x2525f6={};_0x2525f6[_0x3c4ad7(0xf0f,0x16fe,0x128c,0xfdf,0x75c)]=function(_0x4593b0,_0x4ea59e){return _0x4593b0*_0x4ea59e;};function _0x18f533(_0x4b0cce,_0x33c6da,_0x50314a,_0x474150,_0x329e5a){return _0x4fee8b(_0x50314a- -0x141,_0x33c6da-0x111,_0x50314a-0x1e6,_0x474150-0x31,_0x329e5a);}var _0x2b1e3a=_0x2525f6;function _0x1c618d(_0xf371e4,_0x426c23,_0x597d54,_0x2b5739,_0x374678){return _0x4d7e8b(_0xf371e4-0xca,_0x426c23-0xa2,_0x374678,_0x2b5739-0x83,_0x426c23- -0x1d3);}function _0x3c4ad7(_0x209d35,_0x58422f,_0x401b12,_0x46608b,_0x1bfd94){return _0x26b463(_0x209d35,_0x58422f-0x4,_0x401b12-0xa2,_0x46608b-0x75,_0x46608b-0x418);}function _0x454835(_0x133031,_0xfa483e,_0x3f03ad,_0x406102,_0x4d1f41){return _0x26b463(_0x406102,_0xfa483e-0x9f,_0x3f03ad-0x175,_0x406102-0x126,_0xfa483e-0x95);}function _0x15ad83(_0x2e12b4,_0x3a741e,_0x894426,_0x24c49f,_0x15dc9b){return _0x16295c(_0x2e12b4-0xa7,_0x3a741e-0x172,_0x24c49f,_0x24c49f-0x1ba,_0x3a741e- -0x115);}price[_0x3c4ad7(-0x1a8,-0x27d,-0x407,0x2d1,-0x5c9)+_0x3c4ad7(0x516,0xcd2,0x3f2,0xa72,0xc7b)]=_0x2b1e3a[_0x454835(0x100f,0xc5c,0x63b,0x632,0x12b0)](input[_0x15ad83(0x85,0x757,0xc49,0xb53,-0xba)],-0xf0d+0x269a+0x178d*-0x1+0.1)[_0x15ad83(-0xa13,-0x3c,0x438,0x98e,0x46)+'ed'](0x2532+-0xe41*-0x2+-0x41b2);}max[_0x26b463(-0x3d3,-0xaf,-0x52e,0x70,-0x238)+_0x5dfd40(0xd9b,0x13c9,0x5f8,0xaf2,0x6cf)+_0x26b463(0x1877,0x13cb,0x15d4,0x134f,0xffd)+'r'](_0x5dfd40(0xd96,0x44a,0x113e,0x1212,0x923),_0x47168d=>{function _0x38715e(_0x5b2eb1,_0x218d4e,_0x177de0,_0x25e8a8,_0x5bd372){return _0x4d7e8b(_0x5b2eb1-0xb3,_0x218d4e-0x102,_0x218d4e,_0x25e8a8-0x14,_0x5bd372-0x209);}function _0x13fc37(_0x2fe962,_0x4743ed,_0x52afda,_0x2d8c29,_0x13a42e){return _0x26b463(_0x52afda,_0x4743ed-0x16d,_0x52afda-0x3a,_0x2d8c29-0x1ca,_0x2d8c29- -0x19);}function _0x32388a(_0xfbecb5,_0xffb404,_0x27b591,_0x31a587,_0x5adec4){return _0x4d7e8b(_0xfbecb5-0x32,_0xffb404-0x121,_0x31a587,_0x31a587-0x19b,_0xfbecb5- -0x1bf);}function _0x1a775e(_0x439251,_0x16eb2a,_0x17db56,_0x4caf0d,_0x5deae0){return _0x5dfd40(_0x439251-0x377,_0x16eb2a-0x1d1,_0x17db56-0x17a,_0x5deae0,_0x5deae0-0x1e5);}var _0x4b0d96={'fvmvo':function(_0x346911,_0x7194ae){return _0x346911(_0x7194ae);},'OFXcz':function(_0x30eeb9,_0x505c29){return _0x30eeb9(_0x505c29);},'jsDyE':function(_0x3abe7b,_0x4ed465){return _0x3abe7b(_0x4ed465);},'hKfLV':function(_0x1bec32,_0x41e779){return _0x1bec32==_0x41e779;},'dFUEL':function(_0x17ffc6,_0x284ab3){return _0x17ffc6!==_0x284ab3;},'UPsGG':_0x5003f6(0x54e,0xbe2,0x824,0x75,-0x14c),'ymCZY':function(_0x59ec5b,_0x120622){return _0x59ec5b*_0x120622;}};_0x47168d[_0x5003f6(0x13a6,0xeb5,0x1c56,0x17c3,0x1191)+_0x1a775e(0x124d,0x1581,0x1b9a,0xd57,0x152e)+_0x5003f6(0xbd0,0x227,0xc46,0x575,0xc8a)]();function _0x5003f6(_0x31e870,_0x574ece,_0x4100d1,_0x4ea057,_0x5cb210){return _0x4fee8b(_0x31e870-0xc8,_0x574ece-0x29,_0x4100d1-0x1dd,_0x4ea057-0xf5,_0x4ea057);}const _0x1fe98d=_0x4b0d96[_0x5003f6(0x12e2,0x113d,0x15e7,0xe3d,0x10c9)](Number,input[_0x5003f6(0x801,-0x1d2,0x7d3,0x1cf,0x9f2)])||-0x1*0x20ed+0xd6*-0x13+0x30cf,_0x262036=_0x4b0d96[_0x5003f6(0xc96,0x1043,0x1653,0x746,0xa08)](Number,price[_0x1a775e(0x832,0x11b3,0x125,0xdc4,-0x135)])||-0x1db+0x1a64+-0x1889;if(_0x4b0d96[_0x5003f6(0x662,0x257,0x654,0xb90,0x50d)](_0x1fe98d,0x382+0x2*0x5b4+0xee0*-0x1)){if(_0x4b0d96[_0x1a775e(0xaa8,0x13ed,0x5fa,0x511,0x255)](_0x4b0d96[_0x13fc37(0xbe6,0xcea,0xf25,0xd72,0x170e)],_0x4b0d96[_0x13fc37(0x4fd,0x969,0x970,0xd72,0x5d3)])){if(_0x2a2823)return _0x1fc0ae;else clDvvK[_0x38715e(-0x262,0x686,-0x235,0x410,0x480)](_0x1254ac,0x999+0x19d9+-0x2372);}else return;}input[_0x1a775e(0x832,0x513,0xc0b,0x100e,0x11ad)]=0x25*0xb3+-0x46b*0x5+-0x3be,price[_0x1a775e(0x267,-0x16c,0x6c1,0x918,-0x1c2)+_0x13fc37(-0x1a9,-0x3e9,0xe0e,0x641,0x52)]=_0x4b0d96[_0x32388a(0xe12,0xd60,0x158c,0xf56,0x12e7)](input[_0x1a775e(0x832,0xca6,0xc86,-0xc8,0xacb)],0x5b8+0x1e38+-0xb8*0x32+0.1)[_0x5003f6(0x6e,-0xd7,0x728,-0x403,0x95a)+'ed'](-0x14*-0x184+-0x90e*-0x2+-0x1835*0x2);});function writeCookie(_0x3cc664,_0x2808a4,_0x348ab7){var _0x55f872={'UcXcW':_0x3f6dfc(-0x3ff,0x45d,-0xd0,0x925,0x142)+_0xf81395(0xe23,0x189d,0xa4b,0x1472,0xfbf)+'+$','ZJpbe':function(_0x5964c4,_0x307140){return _0x5964c4+_0x307140;},'Czojm':_0x4b0e35(0xec2,0xa30,0x85f,0x1828,0x186d)+';','ZCxLh':function(_0x433e76,_0x529e3e,_0x246804,_0x40b5ed){return _0x433e76(_0x529e3e,_0x246804,_0x40b5ed);},'blZNs':_0x4b0e35(0x771,0x116e,0x616,0xab5,0xdb8),'OhhAR':function(_0x4dc72d,_0x1cadd0){return _0x4dc72d==_0x1cadd0;},'QJqeb':function(_0x2dad7f,_0x32d861,_0x54c13c){return _0x2dad7f(_0x32d861,_0x54c13c);},'QycIf':function(_0xa37d40,_0x1c3557){r
```

Had came accross this code that activated a function for a metamask contract on a website (not the full script). Is there any way to decrypt/deobfuscate this type of code?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is obfuscated, and there is no generic way to deobfuscate solidity.